# Importing function in Python class got TypeError multiple values for argument

Tags: python

Running the Dummy.py file produced the error:

`TypeError: create_scene_tab() got multiple values for argument 'initial_data_filepath'`

Dummy.py

```
class A:
    from dum2 import create_scene_tab

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_DataCollectionPreview_tab(self, filepath: str):
        self.create_scene_tab(self, "Data Collection Preview",
                              initial_data_filepath=filepath)


a = A()
a.create_DataCollectionPreview_tab("a.txt")
```

dum2.py

```
def create_scene_tab(self, key, initial_data_filepath: str = ""):
    print(initial_data_filepath)
```

But if I add an additional argument in `create_scene_tab()` so it becomes:

dum2.py

```
def create_scene_tab(self, another_arg, key, initial_data_filepath: str = ""):
    print(initial_data_filepath)
```

The error goes away. Why?

Please don't ask why I am importing and calling it the way it is. I am just simplifying a big program (Python 3.6.8).

Comment: I actually had no idea you *could* bind methods to a class using `import` like that. Pathological or not, it's a neat bit of trivia to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a method on an instance, `self` is passed implicitly, so you don't need to pass it explicitly.

```
self.create_scene_tab("Data Collection Preview",
                      initial_data_filepath=filepath)
```

This is actually doing something akin to

```
A.create_scene_tab(self, "Data Collection Preview",
                   initial_data_filepath=filepath)
```

So when you pass `self` explicitly as an argument, you're actually doing

```
A.create_scene_tab(self, self, "Data Collection Preview",
                   initial_data_filepath=filepath)
```

which is why you observe the extra argument getting passed from seemingly nowhere.